# How to add view access to members in plone

Tags: fullcalendar, plone

We installed the FullCalendar plugin in Plone 6 and it works perfect for the admin account or when no-one is logged in the systems, but when members login they can only see a "+ and -" signs instead of the render of the calendar, only admin account is able to see the rendering of FullCalendar.

How can I add access to FullCalendar to all members with accounts on Plone?

I've tried to check Zope Management Interface and couldn't figure out which (if necessary) group/role/user permission should I add/modify.

Comment: As you write that non logged in users (anonyma) get the calendar correctly displayed, there should no permissions be required for members either. Does the browser console spit any errors?

Comment: Hi Ida, exactly as you mention, all anonymous users and Admin are able to see the render of the calendar in the screen, all others only see a "+ and -" signs, everyone is able to log new events into the calendar, but only if you sign-off and/or login as admin you will be able to see the calendar. We really don't know how to fixed, i have googled over and over and did't found anything that points me in the right direction :(. any help you can provide will be very welcome!

Comment: That's why I'm suspecting a JS error caused by a script which is only loaded for members. However, if you manage to open a webconsole/webinspector (in firefox possible by pressing Ctrl+Shift+k at once) and find an error, it might be a good idea to check out the repository of the add-on, if there is an issue opened already, respectively open a new one to continue debugging there. There seem to be several fullcalendar add-ons around, what is the exact name of the add-on?

Comment: Hi Ida!  I'm checking this, I hope we can find the issue to finally provide a solution to the users.  Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Please ask for Plone help in our forum https://community.plone.org